# hubotとslackの連携でのエラー　JSON ERROR TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace'

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

APIを叩いて配列にpushするというコードを書きました。

```
lodash = require('lodash')

module.exports = (robot) ->

  URL = "http://..."
  envelope = room: "room"

  request = robot.http("#{URL}/api/...")
                 .get()

  request (err, res, body) ->
    json = JSON.parse body

    row_users = []
    for obj in json['users']
      name = obj['name']
      row_users.push(name)

    users = robot.brain.get(KEY) ? []
    diff = lodash.difference(row_users, users)

    for name in diff
      robot.send envelope, "ユーザーの登録があります #{name}"
```

エラー文

```
ERROR TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace'
[Sun Jan 24 2016 14:02:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace'
2016-01-24T14:02:00.004985+00:00 app[web.1]:   at SlackBot.send (/app/node_modules/hubot-slack/src/slack.coffee:229:47, <js>:278:19)
2016-01-24T14:02:00.004986+00:00 app[web.1]:   at runAdapterSend (/app/node_modules/hubot/src/response.coffee:82:34, <js>:87:50)
2016-01-24T14:02:00.004987+00:00 app[web.1]:   at allDone (/app/node_modules/hubot/src/middleware.coffee:44:37, <js>:34:16)
2016-01-24T14:02:00.004988+00:00 app[web.1]:   at /app/node_modules/hubot/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:13
```

hubotとslackの連携を試みています。
配列をString型に置き換えれてないのが原因でしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーメッセージは、エラー文だけでなく、エラー発生位置も大変重要です。エラーの前後3行ほどは、省略せずに記載してください。これだけでは情報が足りません。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます！編集いたしました。

Comment: 似たようなエラーの記事があります。 http://qiita.com/nodoca/items/87008a468faff5f97398

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。envelope = room: "room"とルームの指定をしていましたが同様になります。。本文にも追加しました。

Comment: hubot と slack の問題ですね。今のままでは回答がつきにくいので、質問を変更されることをオススメします。 例えば「hubot と slack の連携でエラーが起きる」などです。また、初めに記載されたコード部は関係無かったことを考えると、全てのコードと、全てのエラーを貼られる方がより回答が付きやすいと思います。